# No of items in search scope and content source is diferent for same site

Tags: 2010, search, search-scope, content-source

I can see 685 items crawled in crawl log of content source but when I add same site in search scope, then item count which I am getting is only 2.

Stucked with this.. Please let me know what is going wrong.
Thanks for time..